# Capture image using gscam

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I can view a live streaming of my laptop camera in image_view. How can I capture the image using termianl? It can be done by right clicking the image_view window but I need a node to capture image from gscam.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54659/capture-image-using-gscam/) by [Bala](https://answers.ros.org/users/4104/bala/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

can't you just write a small node (10 min work) to take image from gscam and save it ?

---

Originally posted by [navderm](https://answers.ros.org/users/984/navderm/) with karma: 78 on 2013-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1